# eclipse could not be ran

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I reinstalled my windows yesterday and now when I try to open eclipse I face such error

[image]

I don't know what's wrong with my eclipse but I have installed last version of java se

Comment: please, check your jdk + eclipse gets how many bits 32/64-bit. can you first make it equal. i.e. jdk with 32-bit = eclipse 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error, in my case it indicated that I tried to use a 32 bit Eclipse with a 64bit JDK.

Unless you have a specific need for 32bit, I'd recommend you to install both the JDK and Eclipse with 64bit.